# How fast I can get results from Elastic Search with 1 billion documents

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have 1 billion records stored in only one Elastic Search server(https://www.elastic.co/), how much faster I will be able to get simple query results, querying the index? less than one second?

Comment: The answer to your question can be YES... or NO. Every use case is different and depends on so many factors (hardware, mappings, analyzers, queries, etc). You need to try it out and figure out how it goes for you. Then if you spot issues, you can ask more specific questions and ask people to help you.

Comment: Basically it will store only this pair of data (md5 string, other string). The md5 string will be the index. That data will be 1 billion times in the ElasticServer, server hardware is any standard core i5.

Comment: So you're building a key/value cache store. Go ahead and try it out. Since your data is very simple, it'll be very easy to find out.

Comment: queries will be probably under one second right? I cant use other services based in memory, because will eat all the RAM.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to know until you try it out on your hardware with your full data set. Maybe not, but probably yes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I want to make "it depends" a little more concrete based on my experience doing just this, since the answer is "yes it can be tens of milliseconds if you use enough and the right kind of compute."

Elasticsearch is a distributed sharding scheme for Lucene. So first, how fast can Lucene execute? That's a Java library, so ok, how fast can the JVM execute? When you dig down to the last question you realize you're really asking "how fast can I execute a program." That obviously depends on what the program is. The program you can run on an Elasticsearch cluster can actually be extremely complex, so it's not very meaningful to ask "how fast can Elasticsearch work?" without specifying that.

Instead we can try and model the general search program. It breaks down roughly into two phases: query and fetch. If you don't need to fetch documents out of Elasticsearch, only document ids, this will save you a lot of time. The more document content you need to fetch out, the longer it will take. Likewise, in the query phase, the model is not complex ultimately: you will score x documents and each scoring function execution takes y time.

Your choices then are to minimize x or y or both.

To give a strawman example, if when you query you already know a day you want to search, and you accrued the documents by evenly adding the same amount per day for a year, you are only searching ~2,739,726 documents for that search. If you are doing full text search and are able to keep `track_total_hits` off (and thus use [WAND](https://www.elastic.co/blog/faster-retrieval-of-top-hits-in-elasticsearch-with-block-max-wand)) you won't even be scoring every single one of those documents.

If on the other hand you need to score every single document in your index on every search request, just do some math -- how fast would your scoring function need to be to score 1 billion items in 1 second? 1 nanosecond. So for whatever your scoring function is (the query you write), can it execute in 1 nanosecond, and is a 1 second response time acceptable? What about if you need to execute many searches at once?

In practice, in running an ES cluster you try to minimize x and y as best as you can for your domain model, and use something like [rally](https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to load test and verify. In my experience, it is generally easier to minimize x for most use cases than y, in other words, try to figure out how you can filter as you search.

So how fast can you search 1 billion documents in Elasticsearch? Now hopefully you understand how "it depends!"